# Mysql query which do not display rows with not equal value

Tags: mysql, select

I have trivial problem with my mysql query. I'd like to display only rows which has order state different than `6`. But The `id_order` has multiple statues which mean e.g:

```
id_order = 8421
**has two statuses:**
id_order_state=8 and
id_order_state = 6.
```

here is example of my table: [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a166f/2)

I tried with:

```
SELECT * FROM order_history WHERE id_order_state != 6 (but here I need more code that I can't handle)
```

Thanks for any help

EDIT: orders 8421, 8422 should be not displayed in result

Comment: If you run the query in your question against the dataset in your SQLFiddle, you get all rows which have order status not equal to 6. What else do you need? Do you want to exclude all orders that have *ever* had a status 6, for example?

Comment: Exactly I want it "exclude all orders that have ever had a status 6"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT i.* FROM order_history i
left join order_history e 
       on i.id_order = e.id_order and e.id_order_state = 6
WHERE  e.id_order_hitory is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
> SELECT * FROM order_history WHERE id_order_state <> 6
```

or

```
> SELECT * FROM order_history WHERE id_order_state NOT IN ( 6)
```

Comment: But I steel got id_order (8421,8422) in result - but I won't it. Please see my table: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a166f/6

Answer (score 0):

Just like this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM order_history 
WHERE id_order NOT IN 
(SELECT id_order FROM order_history WHERE id_order_state = 6);
```